# How to crop and change size of images with filter_complex on ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using a code to put together some images and make a video that keeps going back and forth in a loop.

The code that I'm using is this:

```
-filter_complex "[0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat,loop=2:80,setpts=N/13/TB" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17
```

It works great, but I need to add a filter to crop images and change their size.
Unfortunately I do not know how to make this work with the code I'm using.

Can anyone help?

This is the complete code that is working:

```
-hide_banner -r 13.000 -threads:v 8 -i "C:/01/test-%02d.JPG" -codec:v copy -filter_complex "[0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat,loop=2:80,setpts=N/13/TB" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -an "C:/01/test.mp4"
```

I already tried putting the filters before the reverse filter, I may have tried it wrong.
Something like:

```
-crop=3300:3300 -scale=900:900
```

I'll explain better. I'm using Avanti GUI, and it has the option of crop and scale, but they do not work when I use with -filter_complex.
I do not know how to manually add the filters correctly.

Comment: You should show the entire command you're using.

Comment: Can't you just add a `crop` and `scale` filter before the `reverse` filter?

Comment: I added the information in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to prepend the `crop` and `scale` filters to the `reverse` filter. You could do it at once (e.g. `[0:v]crop,scale,reverse[r]`, but you need to apply it both to your original video as well as the reversed one, so create two filter chains:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:/01/test-%02d.JPG"  -filter_complex "\
  [0:v]crop=3300:3300,scale=900:900[vid]; \
  [0:v]crop=3300:3300,scale=900:900,reverse[r]; \
  [vid][r]concat,loop=2:80,setpts=N/13/TB[out]" \
  -map "[out"] \
  -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -an \
  "C:/01/test.mp4"
```

Note: Do not use `-codec:v copy` – when you use a filter, you need to let ffmpeg re-encode the video.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

The only change I had to make was to delete all "\" because the Avanti software does not read. I tested by just deleting them from the code and it worked.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, this is just typical Bash syntax to break lines – it's easier to visualize the command that way.